# I want to include haystack search in all pages

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-haystack

I have configured a haystack search for my index page.
I have the configuration like below

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$',SearchView(
    template='index.html',
    form_class=SearchForm),name="haystack_search")
```

But normally when I include my index.html in other pages, i dont see the search bar because it is only configured for  index page. Any ideas, if there is a way to include haystack search as a context to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't give search results the root url, but rather use the line the haystack documentation suggests.

```
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

Then, place a search form in your base template that point to that url in the form action. Any template inheriting from the base will include the form. Again, the [haystack documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) gives really good directions about how you might organise your template code.